# Why elasticsearch dynamic templates create explicit fields in the mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

The document that I want to index is as follows

```
{
 "Under Armour": 0.16667,
 "Skechers": 0.14774,
 "Nike": 0.24404,
 "New Balance": 0.11905,
 "SONOMA Goods for Life": 0.11236
}
```

Fields under this node are dynamic, which means when documents are getting added various fields(brands) will come with those documents.

If I create an index without specifying a mapping, ES says "maximum number of fields (1000) have been reached". Though we can increase this value, it is not a good practice.

In order to support the above document, I created a mapping as follows and created an index.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "template1":{
            "match_mapping_type": "double",
            "match": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I add above document to the created index and checked the mapping of the index again. It looks like as below.

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "template1": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "double",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "New Balance": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Nike": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "SONOMA Goods for Life": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Skechers": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Under Armour": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you clearly see the mapping that I created earlier and the mapping when I added a document to the index is different. It added fields statically added to the mapping. When I keep adding more documents, new fields will be added to the mapping (which will end up with maximum number of fields(1000) has been reached).

My question is,

1. The mapping that I mentioned above is correct for the above mentioned document.
2. If it is correct, why new fields are added to the mapping?

Comment: In your mapping you have only specified a dynamic template based on new  field types. That's simply a shortcut to prevent you from adding dozens/hundreds of fields manually, but ES will still amend the mapping whenever it sees new fields in your document.

Comment: @Val Thanks for the response. What would be the correct mapping in order to comply such documents?

Comment: Your mapping is correct, if you know you'll end up with more than 1000 fields, then you either need to increase that limit or partition your data into difference indices.

Comment: Why not simply changing the structure of your documents to simply have a brand name and a float value ? `{"brand": "Under Armour", "value": 0.16667}` ??? That way you can have millions of brands without worrying about the field count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the posts that I read, increasing the number of fields in an index  is not a good practice it may increase the resource usage.

In this case, when there are enormous number of brands are there and new brands to be introduced.

The proper solution for such a case is, introduce key-value pairs. (Probably I need to do a transformation during ETL)

```
{
  "brands": [
    {
      "key": "Under Armour",
      "value": 0.16667
    },
    {
      "key": "Skechers",
      "value": 0.14774
    },
    {
      "key": "Nike",
      "value": 0.24404
    }
  ]
}
```

When the data is formatted as above, the map won't be change.

A good reading that I found was 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-beginner-troubleshooting#keyvalue-woes

Thanks @Val for the suggestion